# When using Rsync through Gitlab, some folders are not transferred

Tags: gitlab-ci, rsync, strapi

Folders missing after deployment, example: 'build'

Settings in .gitlab-ci.yml
[image: Settings in .gitlab-ci.yml]

files and folders after build
[image: files and folders after build]

Comment: Hmm. What is missing? I see `build` in your screenshot. I noticed you put `/project` at the source for `rsync` is that right? Maybe you want to use `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` instead?

Comment: on the screenshot, the list of files is at the build stage, but when deploying to the server, the 'build', '.tmp' folder is missing

Comment: Can you try adding `--include ".*"` to the `rsync` command? I think hidden directories (those starting with `.`) may be excluded by default.